# How should I understand the difference between the two definitions of measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

According to Wikipedia, the measurable function is defined as "The preimage of each measurable set is a measurable set." But in the book Real and Complex Analysis written by Rudin, the measurable function is defined as "The preimage of each open set is a measurable set." How to understand this difference?[image]

Answer (score 2):

The first one is more general.

The two definitions coincide when  $Y$ is a topological space equipped with its Borel sigma algebra (which is defined as the sigma algebra generated by open sets). (A proof is outlined in my comment below).

Comment: But, if $Y$ is a topological space, then each open set is measurable while the converse is wrong. Therefore I think that the two definitions didn't agree when $Y$ is a topological space. And another question, which one is more general between topological space and measurable space?

Comment: They are equivalent but a proof is required. Consdier the collection of all sets $E$ in $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma$, verify that it contains all open sets and that it is a sigma algebra. This implies that it contains all sets in the Borel sigma algebra. @Charles

Comment: if they are equivalent when $Y$ is a topological space, and there is no inclusion relation between the category of all topological spaces and the category of all measurable spaces, then why the first one is more general?

Comment: @Charles A topoogical space $Y$ with its Borel sigma algebra $T$ is a measurable space. So this is a special case.

Answer (score 1):

If $Y$ is a topological space and if $ \mathcal G$ is the set of open subsets of $Y$ , then it is common to consider the $ \sigma-$ algebra $\sigma( \mathcal G)$ on $Y$.

In this case the obove definitions coincide.

Comment: But, if $Y$ is a topological space, then each open set is measurable while the converse is wrong. Therefore I think that the two definitions didn't agree when $Y$ is a topological space. And another question, which one is more general between topological space and measurable space?

Answer (score 1):

There is a general theorem stating that given a semi-algebra $\mathcal{S}$ generating the sigma algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on $Y$, $f:(X,\Sigma)\rightarrow (Y,\mathcal{A})$ is measurable if and only if $f^{-1}[A]\in \Sigma$ for all $A\in \mathcal{S}$.

In the case of Borel sigma algebras, which are generated by open sets, this coincides with the condition on pre-images of open sets. As stated in the other answers the first one is more general but more complicated to consider.

Comment: But, if $Y$ is a topological space, then each open set is measurable while the converse is wrong. Therefore I think that the two definitions didn't agree when $Y$ is a topological space. And another question, which one is more general between topological space and measurable space?

Comment: Are you asking if a measurable space is more general than a space with a Borel sigma algebra, or if between  a measurable space and a topological space once can be said to be more general? If it is the latter, then that would be like asking if a group is a generalization of topological space or vice versa. In that case none is more general.